# How to implement the AAD auth provider for a web service programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have a simple web app (web API), imagine a default one. I protected it with AAD auth provider [using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-express-settings), creating an app registration on the fly.

In the "Action to take when request is not authenticated" I chose "Log in with Azure Active Directory". And so it works - users from the tenant can access the web after AAD login. I can also [access the API via Postman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), after generating and providing access token.

Now, I want to implement this AAD auth provider in the API code for flexibility (need some anonymous endpoints). How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure your ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD auth  programmatically, you could refer to this sample, it demonstrates how an ASP.NET Core web app can sign in users from any Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) organization.

[Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Joy. What's interesting is that now I cannot access the app with Postman (even providing a valid Bearer token) - I get HTML with "Sign in to your account" instead. Is this expected? And how to get around it then?

Answer (score 0):

Do look in the API log files for the authentication and authorization module.

You set the logging level to Debug in Appsetting.json like

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "Debug"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, do check the response header of the failing request to the API and look for the **WWW-Authenticate:** header.

If present, it can look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```